# Joi nested object operations

Tags: node.js, validation, npm, backend, joi

I have a Joi schema of type:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  a: Joi.string(),
  b: Joi.string(),
  c: Joi.string()
})
```

Now, I want to add a condition that if `a` is not present then both `b` and `c` should be present. I know there are operations like `object.and()` and `object.or()` but I am not sure how to use these in my case i.e. `a or (b and c)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use Joi's alternatives and conditional functionality, which you can read about in the [documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#alternatives)

```
const schema = {
    a: Joi.string(),
    b: Joi.when('a', { is: !Joi.exist(), then: Joi.string().required() }),
    c: Joi.when('a', { is: !Joi.exist(), then: Joi.string().required() }),
};
```